# await return undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, return, undefined

I have the following code:

```
const { list } = await superagent.get(`http://${window.location.host}/api`)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.body);
    return res.body
  })
  console.log(list);
return { list }
```

I am getting res.body, however list is undefined.  does anyone know why list is undefined?  shouldn't the const declaration wait for the return value and assigning it first?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting `res.body` to have a property of `list`? Don't think the issue is with async/await

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with the destructuring. Try removing the brackets and assigning the resolved promise: `const object = await ......... `

Comment: Thanks! that worked!